# Can the OneNote API tell if a page is a sub-page? And if a page has sub-pages?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

Is there any way the OneNote API can report whether a page is a sub-page of another page, and if so, what that parent page is? And vice versa, if a page can report what sub-pages it has?

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa286798%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Office2007OneNoteWhatsNew2_NotebookHierarchyElements

The "isSubPage" attribute should help you find out whether or not the page is a sub page.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response, Dinerdo. In the absence of this facility in the OneNote API (see DaKeller-MSFT's answer below), this could be worth investigating.

Answer (score 2):

The OneNote API (speaking of the one at http://dev.onenote.com/) does not support this at this time. I will have this added to our backlog for consideration.

Comment: Thanks, DaKeller-MSFT. I don't think I'd be the only one to find this a useful addition to the OneNote API.

Comment: There is an uservoice issue that you can go vote on for this feature at https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-apis/suggestions/5779605-provide-api-access-at-the-sub-page-and-sub-sub-pag

Answer (score 1):

We added an optional query param [?pagelevel=true](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2016/02/04/change-page-level/) to our GET/PATCH Pages APIs which now let's you fetch and edit the page's level.

```
GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages/{id}?pagelevel=true
will include in the json a pagelevel property.
where 0 means no indentation at all and 2 is the maximum indentation level.
```

Comment: Excellent, Dipak - this will be very helpful.